# static constructors and BeforeFieldInit?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

> If a type has no static constructor, field initializers will execute
>   just prior to the type being used— or anytime earlier at the whim of
>   the runtime

Why this code :

```
void Main()
{ 
  "-------start-------".Dump();
   Test.EchoAndReturn("Hello");
  "-------end-------".Dump();

}

 class Test
{
    public static string x = EchoAndReturn ("a");
    public static string y = EchoAndReturn ("b");
    public static string EchoAndReturn (string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

yields :

```
-------start-------
a
b
Hello
-------end-------
```

while this code :

```
void Main()
{ 
  "-------start-------".Dump();
   var test=Test.x;
  "-------end-------".Dump();

}
```

yields

```
a
b
-------start-------
-------end-------
```

The order of `a` and `b` is understood. but why dealing with  `static method` is **different** than  `static field`.

I mean why the *start* and *end* lines are in different locations with static methods vs static fields ? I mean - in both situation he's got to initialize those fields...so why ?

*( I know I can add static ctor which make it to be the same - but Im asking about this particular situation. )*

*(p.s. Dump() is just like console.write)*

Comment: should note that if I scroll over your questions, can create good base for HR recruting :)

Comment: @Tigran Yeah. I know. I always like the edge questions. Dont ask me why. ( you can be sure im not dealing with this kind of things in my job). :-)

Comment: are you in debug or release? the behavior may be different

Comment: it is in Linqpad with optimize code flag = on. and linqpad doesnt have debug option so i guess it is release.

Comment: Isn't this simply what "at the whim" means? The compiler is allowed to shuffle things around and now it's doing that. Could be different in the next release.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Still ,  the randomization here yields same const results for static methods and yields another const results for static fields. The question is why

Comment: I tried this on versions from 4.0 to 2.0 and behavior is the same. **If** this is a bug, it's there for too long time...

Comment: For info, I think Linqpad is acting as a debugger here, which means it is having side-effects, and is actually changing the results. For a robust test, you may want to use a console exe.

Comment: This is a classic misconception: The specification doesn't *guarantee* optimal laziness, it simply *allows* laziness. There is a huge difference. Basically the exact extent of laziness is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of the release JIT is (from 4.0 IIRC) not to run the static initializer unless the method you are calling touches static fields. This can mean the static fields **are not** initialized. If I run your first code in release outside of the debugger, I get:

```
-------start-------
Hello
-------end-------
```

If I run it with the debugger attached (release), or in a debug build (with or without debugger attached), I get:

```
-------start-------
a
b
Hello
-------end-------
```

So far so interesting. For why you get:

```
a
b
-------start-------
-------end-------
```

it looks like the per-method JIT is essentially taking responsibility for running the static constructor in this scenario. You can see this by adding:

```
if(NeverTrue()) { // method that returns false
        "-------start-------".Dump();
        var test = Test.x;
        "-------end-------".Dump();
}
```

which will print (even in release without the debugger)

```
a
b
```

so the *possibility* of accessing fields is key. If we change `Test.x` to be a call to a method that *doesn't access fields* (and remove the `NeverTrue()` thing), then we get *no output whatsoever*.

So: in some versions of the CLI, the execution of static initializers may be deferred to the JIT-step of methods that contain mentions to any field (it doesn't check whether that field has an initializer).

We can even create instances of objects without running the static initializer, as long as we don't touch static fields:

```
 public Test()
 {
     a = "";
 }
 string a;
```

with:

```
"-------start-------".Dump();
new Test();
"-------end-------".Dump();
```

prints just (release, no debugger):

```
-------start-------
-------end-------
```

HOWEVER! We should not build anything that depends on this timing:

- it changes between .NET version
- it may well change between platform (x86, x64, CF, SL, .NETCore, etc)
- it can change depending on whether the debugger is attached and whether it is a debug/release build

Comment: so this whole beforeinitField needs to be considered differently with debug/release versions ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir by running a console exe in different ways, it appears the answer is a solid "yes"

Comment: The specification basically just states that the fields will be initialized "at an implementation dependent" time before they are used. The key point to realize here is that it makes *no guarantee whatsoever* about postponing initialization until it is needed. It could run all static field initializers in all classes before it enters Main() and it would be still be compliant. The specification isn't enforcing laziness, it just allows it.

Answer (score 3):

The time when static constuctor will be called is not guaranted, so for the programm it is like Undefined Behavior in C++. Nobody should rely on the sequence of static constructor calls. For example if you compile the programm under release you will see that static counstructor called in the same time in both cases.

Comment: Well not quite. C# specification is much more rigid, and in most cases you can make various guarantees about the outcome. Assuming you encapsulate in certain ways, and initialize in certain ways, the specification is strong enough that you can guarantee the exact outcome. Basically in C# you can't be sure what happens in the general case, but you can design your static initialization in ways that creates strong guarantees. Whereas in C++ it's just an undefined rats nest of pure luck. (C# specification has examples that show what outcome you should expect if you have circular dependencies.)

Answer (score 1):

This is with `.NET 4.0`

If a type has no static constructor but static fields with initialization, the compiler creates a type constructor and puts the initialization inside it.

```
class Test
    {
        public static string x = EchoAndReturn("a");
        public static string y = EchoAndReturn("b");
        public static string EchoAndReturn(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Results in the following IL (Just the cctor part)

```
.method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
        void  .cctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       31 (0x1f)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "a"
  IL_0005:  call       string ConsoleApplication1.Test::EchoAndReturn(string)
  IL_000a:  stsfld     string ConsoleApplication1.Test::x
  IL_000f:  ldstr      "b"
  IL_0014:  call       string ConsoleApplication1.Test::EchoAndReturn(string)
  IL_0019:  stsfld     string ConsoleApplication1.Test::y
  IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method Test::.cctor
```

Also, according to `CLR via C#`, the JIT compiler checks each method beforehand, what types have a static constructor. If the static constructor has not been called, the JIT compiler calls it.

That would explain the difference between the two code fragments.

> ```
> When the just-in-time (JIT) compiler is compiling a method,
> ```
>
> it sees what types are referenced in the code .If any of the types define
>   a type constructor, the JIT compiler checks if the type’s type
>   constructor has already been executed for this AppDomain .If the
>   constructor has never executed, the JIT compiler emits a call to the
>   type constructor into the native code that the JIT compiler is
>   emitting .

@Comment

If you move one field initializer into a user-defined type constructor, the compiler will move the other field you initialize on the class level into the type constructor as well.

```
static Test()
{
  y = EchoAndReturn("b");
}
```

Results in the same IL as above. So there basically is no difference between your own type constructor and the one generated by the compiler (There can only be one anyway).

Comment: So it craetes a "fake" ctor ? if so whats the diff between creating his own ctor vs a ready ctor ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir added a response. Not sure though what you mean by ready ctor. Also note that the static constructor is a "cctor" while the instance constructor is a "ctor".