# When are static fields initialized in C#?

Tags: c#

I've written a class like this:

```
class Singleton
{
    private Singleton()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized.");
        Singleton.num++;
    }

    public static uint num;

    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton.instance; }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

And in my main method, if I wrote like this:

```
        Console.WriteLine("====================");
        Singleton s = Singleton.Instance;
        Console.WriteLine("====================");
        //Console.WriteLine(Singleton.num);
```

I got a output like:

```
====================
Initialized.
====================
```

But if I uncomment the last line, I'll got a output like this:

```
Initialized.
====================
====================
1
```

Why the constructor was inkoved before any process in the second case? And why the last line will effect its previous procedures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c

Comment: Note that you don't need to specify a setter on a property - it's perfectly fine to have a property that has only a setter, or only a getter.

Comment: Observation: The first output only occurs in debug builds; release builds always call the static constructor at startup before Main() is called. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12816842/106159